# Fit-screen dosn't fill all the screen

Tags: macos, safari, display, fullscreen

I'm new Mac user, on Yosemite.

Some apps, like Chrome Sublime Text,  when I double click on the title bar doesn't fit my screen, check the image  [image]
Also for some others apps, Like Xcode or Safari it works fine - double click on the title makes my app fit full screen.

How to fix?

Comment: Actually you are not asking to fill the screen, but to only fill the window.

Answer (score 2):

Fit screen & full screen are not the same thing.

Fit screen makes a 'guess' based on window content & probable usage [per app, it would appear to not be consistent, some apps are better than others at 'guessing']

Full screen is under system control & will generate a new Space for the app, filling the entire screen.

Clicking the green dot, top left of a window, will set Full-screen.
Alt [opt] clicking the same dot will set to fit-screen.

Comment: Good thank's for explaining so the fit screen depends of the apps guessing and it's not the some from one app to others ?

Comment: @Chlebta basically "fit screen" is the classical behaviour of the green button and its purpose is to stretch application window to wrap all its contents, but not more. Full screen is more similar to Windows where you fill your entire screen with application window, including empty spaces unused by window contents.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, use the keyboard <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to go in to full screen mode.

Use it again to exit full screen.

To fill in the Window (not the screen) I recommend the Chrome Extension called "iZoom", found here

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/izoom/iheccogfcpjfjbnlohnlgdljaefpgaoi?hl=en-US

> Automatically changes zoom level to fit window width. With three
>   different zooming modes.

Comment: This for full screen but I need fit screen and thank's for keyboard shortcuts

Comment: So it is not the screen, but the window in the screen. The way you do that is use the cmd+ or cmd- to adjust the size displayed in the window, not in the screen.

Comment: In chrome cmd+ will make my content more bigger not the windows size